# Connection between the eulogy of Shaul by Dovid and Nedarim

Tags: mishna, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david, tractate-nedarim

Two Mishnayos in Nedarim, [3:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.3.11) and [9:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.9.10), contain quotes from the eulogy of Shaul by Dovid .  Both quotes are tangents, they don't directly relate to each other in context, and neither is really integral to the message of the mishnah.  As far as I know there are no other quotes from this Kinah (eulogy) anywhere in mishnayos, though there is one in the Gemara in [Avodah Zara 25a](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.25a.11).

This seems too unlikely to just be a coincidence.  Does anyone develop a deeper connection between Nedarim and Kinas David?